# Input type-file not showing up even with FileReader

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an input type-file, append it to unordered list and make it show up in browser
But it's not showing up and browser not showing any errors
Please help. I am trying to solve this problem already 3 days. I recently started coding, please don't make fun of me
This is my own project in order to learn better JavaScript

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>javascripttutorial</title>
<style>
    .name-div {
        color: aliceblue;

    }
    .photo-div {
        color: aliceblue;

    }
    .date-div {
        color: aliceblue;

    }
    .box-1 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
    .box-2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 500px;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    .box-3 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 500px;
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        
    }
    body {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }</style> <script src="script.js"></script></head><body>
<div style="margin: 10px;" class="name-div">
    <input id="input-name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
</div>
<div style="margin: 10px;" class="photo-div">
    <input id="input-photo" type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
    <img src="" height="100" alt="Image preview...">
</div>
 <div style="margin: 10px;" class="date-div">
    <input id="input-date"  type="date" placeholder="Your birthday">
</div>
<div style="margin: 10px;" class="button-div">
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
</div>
<span class="box-1">
    <ul id="messages-1">Name:    </ul>
</span>
<span class="box-2">   
    <ul id="messages-2">Photo:    </ul>
</span>
<span class="box-3">
    <ul id="messages-3">Date:     </ul>
</span>
<script async src="script.js"></script></body></html>>
```

My script

```js
window.onload=function(){
var inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
var inputPhoto = document.getElementById('input-photo');
var inputDate = document.getElementById('input-date');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var messages1 = document.getElementById('messages-1');
var messages2 = document.getElementById('messages-2');
var messages3 = document.getElementById('messages-3');
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
 var newMessage1 = document.createElement("li");
 var newMessage2 = document.createElement("li");
 var photo = document.createElement("img");
 var newMessage3 = document.createElement("li");
 newMessage1.innerHTML = inputName.value;
 photo.setAttribute("style", "height: 30px; widht: 30px;");
 var reader1 = new FileReader();
 reader1.addEventListener("onloadend", function(){
   reader1.readAsDataURL(inputPhoto);
   photo.src = reader1.result;
 });
 newMessage3.innerHTML = inputDate.value;
 messages1.appendChild(newMessage1);
 messages2.appendChild(newMessage2)
 messages3.appendChild(newMessage3);
 newMessage2.appendChild(photo);
 inputName.value = "";

 inputDate.value = "";
});
}
function previewFile() {
 var preview = document.querySelector('img');
 var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
 var reader  = new FileReader();

 reader.onloadend = function () {
   preview.src = reader.result;
 }

 if (file) {
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 } else {
   preview.src = "";
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't see input type file in HTML nor in you js file

Comment: @KonradLinkowski  - There is an input file type in both the markup and the code. The only problem is with the button click function.  OP wants to append the selected image file to a list which shows the name, date, and a thumbnail image.  And that is the part that is not working.  Yet, I think it could work with only minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

## Steps to Follow

Listen to the `change` event fire by the image file upload input on an image upload.

1. Grab the file from the parameter that receives to the event listener callback.
2. Then pass it to the `FileReader`.
3. That's it in here.

```js
inputPhoto.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Now listen to the `load` event fire by the FileReader.

1. Get the base64 from the parameter.
2. Create an image element to preview the uploaded image.
3. Then set the base64 to that image `src` attribute.

```js
fileReader.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  var imgUploadWrap = document.getElementsByClassName("photo-div")[0];
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  var base64 = e.target.result;

  img.setAttribute("id", "uploaded-img");
  img.height = 100;
  img.src = base64;
  imgUploadWrap.append(img);
});
```

**Notes:**

- I create a new image element on upload because it will be easier to reset it.
- If you listen to the `load` event, not `loadend`, then you don't have to handle the file empty scenario because the `load` event is fired only if the upload is successful.

Finally when clicking the submit button, set the preview image element's src attribute to the image element inside the message.

```js
if (uploadedImg) {
  photo.height = 60;
  photo.src = uploadedImg.src;
  uploadedImg.remove();
}
```

Full Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/input-type-file-not-showing-up-even-with-filereader-71891729-u5bvft?file=/script.js

Comment: Good answer.  Where are you resetting file input to allow it to it to be used again?  I see that it works in your demo, but could not spot where it was reset.  +1

Comment: I think @Yogi it's not necessary to reset the file upload according to the current UI. Just resetting the upload image element is sufficient.